# Drawing curved text in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, curve

I wish to draw text along a given vector (which might be anything - not necessarily elliptical or straight). The text must be remain tangential to the curve, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807614/draw-rotated-text-on-curved-path).

The way to do it along some simple equation (a straight or elliptic line) is relatively simple in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159845/curved-text-in-java). 
However, this would be complicated in MATLAB:

1. converting every character to an image using *insertText()* or *vision.TextInserter*
2. computing the coordinates of each character in a straight line
3. computing an adequate transformation using TFORM
4. applying it for each character using *imwarp()*

Since the code is going to create at least thousands of images, each one with several characters, and will include other rendering operations, I am looking for a simpler/more economical way.

Moreover, this provides no solution in the case of a general vector.

Any suggestions? Adding libraries is not a problem if this can solve the problem.

Comment: I can't see any other way other than what you have proposed.  MATLAB was meant for data analysis and processing... and perhaps creating some nice looking GUIs, but never something as sophisticated as drawing text tangential to a curved vector.  IMO, I don't think there's a simple way in doing it other than what you have already described!

Comment: Thanks! Then could you suggest some other script based language/environment which will do the job?

Comment: If the [java example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159845/curved-text-in-java) you linked to is good enough for you then you're ok. Matlab can integrate `Java` libraries relatively well. Look at the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this as well and decided to write my own:

[image: Curvy text example]

```
function curvytext(xy,str,varargin)
%//
%// Input: 
%//     xy          2-by-n matrix of x (row 1) and y (row 2) coordinates
%//                 describing any 2D path
%//     str         length m string to be plotted
%//     varargin    standard variable arguments for modifying text
%//                 appearance
%//
    if size(xy,1)>2; xy=xy'; end; 
    n = size(xy,2);
    m = length(str);

    XY = spline(1:n,xy,linspace(1,n,m+1));
    dXY = XY(:,2:end)-XY(:,1:end-1);
    theta = (arrayfun(@(y,x) atan2(y,x),dXY(2,:),dXY(1,:)))/2/pi*360;

    XY = (XY(:,1:end-1)+XY(:,2:end))/2;
    plot(XY(1,:),XY(2,:),'k-'); hold on;
    for i=1:m
        text(XY(1,i),XY(2,i),str(i),'rotation',theta(i),...
             'horizontalalignment','center','verticalalignment','bottom',varargin{:});
    end
    axis equal
end
```

As written in the commented portion of the code, the input `xy` is a `2-by-n` matrix that describes any 2D path. The input `str` is the text to plot, and `varargin` allows you to specify any standard `Name,Value` pairs just as you would using `text`.

**How it works:**

`spline` and `linspace(1,n,m+1)` together parameterize the curve into `m+1` equally spaced pieces, where `m` is the number of characters in `str`.

`dXY` computes the differences between pairs of consecutive points.

`arrayfun` and `atan2` compute the rotation angle (in radians) for each letter.

`XY = (XY(:,1:end-1)+XY(:,2:end))/2;` averages consecutive pairs of points so that the `m` letters are plotted in between the `m+1` interpolated points.

Then we loop over each character using `text` and the `rotation` property (converted to degrees). Notice `varargin` is fed into the `text` command.

Comment: Your solution is short, elegant, and much simpler than my suggestion. Even though I finally solved the problem with plain C/ImageMagick, your solution definitely solves the problen. Thanks!

Comment: @Geoff, I can't get this to provide a curved text along the line: `curvytext([10:20;(10:20).^2],'This is a test')`. See figure here: db.tt/Kr4Bn25H.

Comment: @TobiasDK the last line of the script, `axis equal`, is important to preserve the aspect ratio. If you're changing the axis after using `curvytext` the letters won't look perpendicular to the curve, even though they technically are.

Comment: @TobiasDK one idea if you must have unequal aspect ratio is to add a third input argument before `varargin`, say `c`, that rotates the letters by some additional constant value `c`. By playing with that value you can probably get the desired effect.

Comment: @Geoff, thanks for the answer. It will not give me the desired output, so I'll just do it in tikz - LaTeX :-). Good day to you.